# Using a boundary file from a shape file in a BayesX model

Tags: r, spatial, bayesian, shapefile, random-effects

I am using a shape file `.shp` and then converting it to a boundary file `.bnd` using `BayesX` to use it as a random effect in my model. But it throws back an error of `ERROR: map is disconnected, spatial effect cannot be estimated` from the`BayesX` log file. What could be the problem

Here is the code

```
fileUrl <- "http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm2.8/shp/ZAF_adm_shp.zip"
download.file(fileUrl, destfile = "ZAF_adm_shp.zip")
unzip(zipfile = "ZAF_adm_shp.zip",exdir = "ZAF_adm_shp")
library(BayesX)
library("R2BayesX")
shpname <- file.path(getwd(), "ZAF_adm_shp" , "ZAF_adm2")
SA_bnd <- BayesX::shp2bnd(shpname = shpname, regionnames = "ID_2", check.is.in = F)
za <- bayesx(dp2011 ~ code +   sx(ID_2, bs = "mrf", map = SA_bnd) +
               sx(ID_2, bs = "re"), iter = 1200,  step = 10, data = data)
```

And here is the data

```
data<-dput(structure(list(ID_2 = 1:52, NAME_2B = structure(c(1L, 3L, 5L, 
10L, 6L, 24L, 30L, 33L, 20L, 26L, 27L, 51L, 40L, 18L, 12L, 36L, 
13L, 50L, 2L, 19L, 23L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 52L, 38L, 
8L, 28L, 47L, 48L, 37L, 17L, 22L, 32L, 21L, 25L, 29L, 35L, 39L, 
4L, 14L, 31L, 15L, 11L, 7L, 9L, 16L, 34L, 49L), .Label = c("Alfred Nzo", 
"Amajuba", "Amathole", "Bojanala", "Buffalo City", "Cacadu", 
"Cape Winelands", "Capricorn", "Central Karoo", "Chris Hani", 
"City of Cape Town", "City of Johannesburg", "City of Tshwane", 
"Dr Kenneth Kaunda", "Dr Ruth Segomotsi Mompati", "Eden", "Ehlanzeni", 
"Ekurhuleni", "eThekwini", "Fezile Dabi", "Frances Baard", "Gert Sibande", 
"iLembe", "Joe Gqabi", "John Taolo Gaetsewe", "Lejweleputswa", 
"Mangaung", "Mopani", "Namakwa", "Nelson Mandela Bay", "Ngaka Modiri Molema", 
"Nkangala", "O.R.Tambo", "Overberg", "Pixley ka Seme", "Sedibeng", 
"Sekhukhune", "Sisonke", "Siyanda", "Thabo Mofutsanyane", "Ugu", 
"Umgungundlovu", "Umkhanyakude", "Umzinyathi", "Uthukela", "Uthungulu", 
"Vhembe", "Waterberg", "West Coast", "West Rand", "Xhariep", 
"Zululand"), class = "factor"), code = structure(c(38L, 5L, 1L, 
6L, 4L, 7L, 51L, 8L, 13L, 10L, 50L, 9L, 11L, 47L, 49L, 36L, 52L, 
41L, 18L, 48L, 22L, 14L, 15L, 20L, 17L, 16L, 21L, 19L, 37L, 29L, 
27L, 28L, 30L, 40L, 26L, 24L, 25L, 46L, 39L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 31L, 
35L, 32L, 33L, 2L, 12L, 42L, 34L, 23L, 3L), .Label = c(" BUF", 
" CPT", " DC1", " DC10", " DC12", " DC13", " DC14", " DC15", 
" DC16", " DC18", " DC19", " DC2", " DC20", " DC21", " DC22", 
" DC23", " DC24", " DC25", " DC26", " DC27", " DC28", " DC29", 
" DC3", " DC30", " DC31", " DC32", " DC33", " DC34", " DC35", 
" DC36", " DC37", " DC38", " DC39", " DC4", " DC40", " DC42", 
" DC43", " DC44", " DC45", " DC47", " DC48", " DC5", " DC6", 
" DC7", " DC8", " DC9", " EKU", " ETH", " JHB", " MAN", " NMA", 
" TSH"), class = "factor"), dp2011 = c(9.7, 7.1, 11.5, 11, 7.2, 
10.7, 13.8, 12.6, 5.8, 8.2, 7.9, 12.3, 11.7, 10.8, 15.5, 7.6, 
8.1, 17.6, 11.3, 33.5, 18.4, 12.5, 14.7, 15.8, 8.9, 8.8, 20.3, 
17.6, 10.5, 10.5, 14.6, 16.4, 8.5, 10.7, 7.1, 6.6, 7.5, 9.9, 
7.5, 4.8, 11, 7.9, 5.4, 11.6, 12.5, 8.3, 14.9, 29.2, 30.7, 8.5, 
16.5, 15.8)), .Names = c("ID_2", "NAME_2B", "code", "dp2011"), row.names = c(NA, 
-52L), class = "data.frame"))
```

Comment: The call to `bayesx()` gives me, after a few seconds `"an error occurred during runtime of BayesX, please check the BayesX logfile!`" but no clue where the logfile is.

Comment: This command helps to get the log file `log <- bayesx_logfile(za )` . I realised the shape file from http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm2.8/shp/ZAF_adm_shp.zip had an issue. I changed it and it just worked